# UpdateCellRequest overrides cell format in spreadsheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Using c# client for v4 of the API.

Creating a request as follows:

```
var updateValuesRequest = new Request() { 
    UpdateCells = new UpdateCellsRequest() { 
        Rows = range.rows, 
        Start = new GridCoordinate() { 
            SheetId = sheetId, 
            RowIndex = range.rowIndex, 
            ColumnIndex = range.columnIndex 
        }, 
        Fields = "*" 
    } 
};
```

When defining the CellData I'm not specifying CellFormat, it still overrides the existing cell format in the sheet by some default formatting.

How can I make sure that the existing cell format is not changed when updating the values via the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified "*" as your fields, meaning you are asking to overwrite every field.  If the data for the field isn't present, then that means to revert it to the default.

If you want to only set some specific portions of the data, you must list those fields explicitly in "fields".

See https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate#field_masks for more information.

Comment: Didn't understand the Fields parameter before, it makes sense now. Tthank you very much